# Visualization and Clustering in Python

Tags: python, nlp, k-means

I would like to classify comments based on NLP algorithm (tf-idf). 
I managed to classify these clusters but I want to visualize them graphically (histogram, scatter plot...)

```
import collections
from nltk import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.stem import PorterStemmer
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from pprint import pprint
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import nltk
import pandas as pd
import string
data = pd.read_excel (r'C:\Users\cra\One\intern\Book2.xlsx') 
def word_tokenizer(text):
        #tokenizes and stems the text
        tokens = word_tokenize(text)  
        stemmer = PorterStemmer() 
        tokens = [stemmer.stem(t) for t in tokens if t not in 
        stopwords.words('english')] 
        return tokens 

#tfidf convert text data to vectors 

def cluster_sentences(sentences, nb_of_clusters=5):
        tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=word_tokenizer,

        stop_words=stopwords.words('english'),#enlever stopwords
                                        max_df=0.95,min_df=0.05, 
           lowercase=True) 

        tfidf_matrix = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(sentences) 
        kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=nb_of_clusters)
        kmeans.fit(tfidf_matrix)
        clusters = collections.defaultdict(list)
        for i, label in enumerate(kmeans.labels_):
                clusters[label].append(i)
        return dict(clusters)
if __name__ == "__main__":
         sentences = data.Comment
        nclusters= 20
        clusters = cluster_sentences(sentences, nclusters) #dictionary of 
        #cluster and the index of the comment in the dataframe
        for cluster in range(nclusters):
                print ("cluster ",cluster,":")
                for i,sentence in enumerate(clusters[cluster]):
                        print ("\tsentence ",i,": ",sentences[sentence])
```

result that I got for example :
cluster  6 :
        sentence  0 :  26    RIH  DP std
        sentence  1 :  32    RIH  DP std
        sentence  2 :  68    RIH  Liner with DP  std  in hole
        sentence  3 :  105   RIH DP std
        sentence  4 :  118   RIH std no  of  DP in hole
        sentence  5 :  154   RIH DP  std

Could you help me please! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use t-SNE to visualize the clusters - this article on [visualizing and clustering US Laws](https://beckernick.github.io/law-clustering/) using tf-idf can get you started.